# Dictionary in swift

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2

```
let json: [AnyObject] = {
            "response": "get_nearby_deals",
            "userID": "12345", 
            "demo":[{"deal_code":"iD1612061"}]
            }
```

How to declare Dictionary in Swift? I'm new in Swift. Totally stuck.

Comment: Basically: `[]` containing **one** type is always an array, containing **two** types colon separated is a dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You have declared `Array` using `[AnyObject]`, just change it to `[String: Any]` and replace curly braces `{}` with square brackets `[]`.

```
let json: [String: Any] = [
                           "response": "get_nearby_deals",
                           "userID": "12345", 
                           "demo":[["deal_code":"iD1612061"]]
                          ]
```

And you can retrieve value from `Dictionary` using `subscript` like this.

```
let userID = json["userID"] as! String
//Above will crash if `userID` key is not exist or value is not string, so you can use optional wrapping with it too.
if let userID = json["userID"] as? String {
    print(userID)
}

//`demo` value is an array of [String:String] dictionary(s)
let demo = json["demo"] as! [[String:String]]
//Same here as the previous `userID`, it will crash if 'demo' key is not exist, so batter if you optionally wrapped it:
if let demo = json["demo"] as? [[String:String]] {
    print(demo)
}
```

Comment: response is in dis form { }

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Have you try once like my answer.

Comment: I voted up, but I suggest to add some code to show how to get values from it because it's [String: Any]; That would be nice :)

Comment: @Nirav ur answer works but my response from server is with curly brace

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas In Swift Dictionary will be noted with `[:]`. I have also edited answer with how to fetch value from dictionary.

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas The server sends JSON. A JSON dictionary/array has a different syntax than a Swift dictionary/array. JSON array: `[]`, JSON dictionary: `{:}`, Swift array: `[]`, Swift dictionary: `[:]`.

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Are you getting now, or you want something else?

Comment: @Eric Aya can u give an example of declaring Json dictionary {:}

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas It is same like my answer.

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Nirav is right. You don't declare directly the JSON syntax. You take a Swift dictionary that you convert to JSON. Or you take a JSON dictionary that you convert to Swift. Please explore [my JSON answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a2227743%20json) if you're still not sure, there's lots of examples - I don't want to write the same stuff again. ;)

Comment: @Nirav I'm using swift2

Comment: @ThripthiHaridas Happy to hear that its solved :) Happy Programming :)